# play2-elastic does not work when ElasticSearch is installed on EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

When I'm trying to connect to ElasticSearch (elasticsearch-0.90.3) installed on EC2 from a none local machine using play2-elastic plugin it throws the following exception (the plugin works fine when connecting locally)

```
error] application - ElasticSearch : No ElasticSearch node is available. Please check that your configuration is correct, that you ES server is up and reachable from the network. Index has not been created and prepared.
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:205) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportIndicesAdminClient.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractIndicesAdminClient.exists(AbstractIndicesAdminClient.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.exists.indices.IndicesExistsRequestBuilder.doExecute(IndicesExistsRequestBuilder.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-0.90.3.jar:na]
```

I have used different methods to test the elasticsearch server is up and running, examples:

```
curl -XGET '184.72.55.204:9300/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d 'this is a test'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server


telnet 184.72.55.204 9300
Trying 184.72.55.204...
Connected to ec2-184-72-55-204.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

In some google groups I also saw other people having similar problem, they seem to be able to fix the problem with turning sniffing to off, so I have this in my application.conf

```
elasticsearch.client="184.72.55.204:9300"
elasticsearch.sniff=false # I ADDED THIS BUT DID NOT HELP
elasticsearch.index.name="phonotags"
elasticsearch.index.settings="{ analysis: { analyzer: { my_analyzer: { type: \"custom\", tokenizer: \"standard\" } } } }"
elasticsearch.index.clazzs="indexing.*"
elasticsearch.index.show_request=true
```

my build.scala file contains these:

```
"com.clever-age" % "play2-elasticsearch" % "0.7-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += Resolver.url("play-plugin-releases", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
resolvers += Resolver.url("play-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

I appreciate your help. 
thanks

Answer (score -1):

It seems your node is not available

```
curl -XPUT '184.72.55.204:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{ "user": "kimchy", "post_date" : "2011-08-18T16:20:00", "message" : "trying out Elastic Search" }'
```

Can you check this ?

Comment: curl -XPUT '184.72.55.204:9300/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{ "user": "kimchy", "post_date" : "2011-08-18T16:20:00", "message" : "trying out Elastic Search" }'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: I have also test the node with telnet, it is accessible and seem to be working fine

Comment: It is very frustrating to use a plugin to save 1 or 2 hours but you end up spending days figuring the plugin! :)

Comment: What AMI do you use ? I try with a ubuntu precise and it's work greats

Comment: Hi nboire, I'm using standard Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: I'm using elasticsearch-0.90.3 
there is no security for the elasticsearch on the box, if it helps please feel free to just hit it. 184.72.55.204:9300